# ここを行かれる　meaning

Tags: translation, particle-を, sentence

I found the sentence in my textbook.

ここをまっすぐ行かれますと、右手に受付がございます。

Why を is used with　行かれる (行く)  here ? I think it should be　に/へ.

If possible, I'd like a translation. Thank you very much !